# Generating Infinite Terrain

Tags: java, android, serialization, libgdx

So I am creating a top down 2D survival game using Libgdx.  My problem is that I can generate terrain **starting at (0,0)** and working up and right, but I want my player to **start at (0,0)** and have terrain generate all around him.  As he walks I want the terrain to either be generated before hand, or be constantly generated dynamically while he is walking around in the world.  How would I implement something like this?  I have a grass texture and I want that texture (at least for right now) to be the only texture generated.

Each tile is stored as an object.  (for serialization) Here is the code for each tile I generate and put in an ArrayList to be rendered later on.

```
public abstract class Tile implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 0;
int ID;
float x,y,w,h;
Texture texture;
boolean isVisible, isCollidable;
Rectangle bounds;

public Tile(float x, float y, float w, float h){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.ID = 0;
    isVisible = false;
    isCollidable = false;
    bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);

    if(this instanceof Grass){
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("terrain/grass.png"));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use TiledMap for this? They can also be programmatically generated and they would already solve a lot of problems for you.

Comment: IF you are going to do it yourself use an Atlas and create the `Textures` out of an `TextureRegion`. Else you will have alot of bind calls in OpenGL and that will reduce the performance alot. I would recommend to preload the Atlas/Textures so the creation is way faster. But as @noone said. Use the TMX map. You can create them on runtime and they do have an optimized render plus they do exactly what you would like to have. Try to not use much different TileSets per layer... https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Tile-maps there is also a test where he creates a tiledmap on runtime in git

Comment: Best way to do this is use Tilemap.